# Is it necessary to check if camera exists when targeting iOS 6+?

Tags: ios, ios6, camera, avfoundation

I am making an app that makes use of the camera in multiple areas and it came upon me that all devices that support iOS 6+ have a camera. This is more of a programming practice question than a practical implementation question.

Apple never explicitly recommends that you *have* to check for a camera, but many developers do.

Is it safe to not check? What are the implications of ***NOT*** checking for a camera?

Is there any performance advantage/disadvantage?

Thanks,

Virindh Borra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs for the `UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:` method:

> Because a media source may not be present or may be unavailable, devices may not always support all source types. For example, if you attempt to pick an image from the user’s library and the library is empty, this method returns NO. Similarly, if the camera is already in use, this method returns NO.
>
> Before attempting to use an UIImagePickerController object to pick an image, you must call this method to ensure that the desired source type is available.

So yes Apple does tell you to check. Besides, how hard is it to do:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    // show camera
} else {
    // don't show camera
}
```

Comment: its not about how hard it is! Ive been thinking about this one for a long time.... but anyway isn't there a difference between availability and existence? just wondering :)

Comment: Good question. I don't think there is any way to know the difference between existing and currently available. But as you said, all currently supported iOS devices have a camera so it should be safe to assume that this method tells you about current availability since you know it exists.

Comment: Oh yeah - the hard/easy comment was really meant to say - since it is so easy, there's no good reason not to check.